# Copy list items an use

Tags: custom-list, item

We have a list in SharePoint 2010 with a number of site columns that need to be filled in based on a content type. However, users want to be able to take a copy of an existing item and then automatically use this once they add a new item. The benefits would be that as such the process speed would be improved.

How can this be achieved easiest? I believe there is no OOTB available to do the same.

Comment: You want to create a new item, copy an existing item and edit it?

Answer (score 1):

A manually initiated workflow sounds like the best option to me. You can either copy the item as is or choose to create a new item and copy bits and pieces of the existing item to the new item.